# Azure Media Services v3 - Event Grid Job progress events missing

Tags: azure-media-services

Azure Media Services v3 - Event Grid subscription not reporting job progress events.

Created an event grid subscription with endpoint type **Web Hook** - subscribed to **All** events.

Expecting to get progress events, but instead only getting job state changes.

**How do I receive the job progress as well?**

The only job events being received are the following.

- Microsoft.Media.JobScheduled
- Microsoft.Media.JobOutputStateChange
- Microsoft.Media.JobOutputStateChange
- Microsoft.Media.JobStateChange
- Microsoft.Media.JobProcessing
- Microsoft.Media.JobOutputProcessing
- Microsoft.Media.JobOutputFinished
- Microsoft.Media.JobOutputStateChange
- Microsoft.Media.JobStateChange
- Microsoft.Media.JobFinished

**Raw Event Data**

```
{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/amsaccount",
  "subject": "transforms/Transcribe-VideoAnalyzerPreset-Transform/jobs/Transcribe AzureTest TestFilter 071min 636795822392514253",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputProcessing",
  "eventTime": "2018-12-05T04:52:30.295037",
  "id": "bc381a10-6ceb-4e0b-9401-a1783dbd7248",
  "data": {
    "previousState": "Scheduled",
    "output": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset",
      "assetName": "d08ebed45dd54256b7fc7448dd466c96",
      "error": null,
      "label": "VideoAnalyzerPreset_0",
      "progress": 0,
      "state": "Processing"
    },
    "jobCorrelationData": {
      "TransformName": "Transcribe-VideoAnalyzerPreset-Transform"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "1.0",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}

{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/1234/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/amsaccount",
  "subject": "transforms/Transcribe-VideoAnalyzerPreset-Transform/jobs/Transcribe AzureTest TestFilter 071min 636795822392514253",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Media.JobOutputFinished",
  "eventTime": "2018-12-05T04:55:28.0774072",
  "id": "eba19e9c-1ee2-4b22-8844-1cf8366f56cb",
  "data": {
    "previousState": "Processing",
    "output": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset",
      "assetName": "d08ebed45dd54256b7fc7448dd466c96",
      "error": null,
      "label": "VideoAnalyzerPreset_0",
      "progress": 100,
      "state": "Finished"
    },
    "jobCorrelationData": {
      "TransformName": "Transcribe-VideoAnalyzerPreset-Transform"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "1.0",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}
```

Comment: We are working to deploy the service updates to support JobOutput progress events. Will report back when the deployments are complete. Thanks

Comment: Is there an estimate?  For example weeks, months?

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to [Azure Event Grid schemas for Media Services events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-event-schemas), as @AnilMurching said, `Monitoring Job Output State Changes` support to get the progress property from job event schemas, but no estimate for time.

To get time estimate for a job, a workaround way is to compute with asset size, the average time cost of other jobs and other helpful arguments to get an approximate value.